# do while in Java doesn't work

Tags: java, do-while

I have following do while code, where I am trying to end the loop when the text entered is Stop. However even though when I type Stop in the console, it doesn't work. I tried to debug it and see it tries to compare the Stop text but doesn't stops it. I don't understand what is the problem.
This is a java code running in eclipse.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application8_Switch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string to match the output");
    String text;
    do {
      text = input.nextLine();
      switch (text) {

        case "start":
          System.out.println("Machine started");
          break;

        case "end":
          System.out.println("This Machine stopped");
          break;

        default:
          System.out.println("Command not recognized");
          break;
      }

    } while (text != "Stop");


  }
}
```

Comment: != is comparing by reference. You need to use .Equals for value comparison. Try !text.Equals("Stop")

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string to match the output");
        String text;
        do {
            text = input.nextLine();
            switch (text) {

            case "start":
                System.out.println("Machine started");
                break;

            case "end":
                System.out.println("This Machine stopped");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Command not recognized");
                break;
            }
        } while (!text.equals("Stop"));
```

**Modifications:**

1. Used `!text.equals("Stop")` because `==` checks by comparing references. However You need to use `equals()` method to check its content.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Java aren't compared using `==` or `!=` like you think they would be.

Instead of using `text != "Stop"`, use `!text.Equals("Stop")`.